# Cannot run 'dd' command in Visual Studio 2010 immediate window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windbg, sos

I am debugging a managed application using [Son of Strike](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) (SOS) in Visual studio 2010. I want to run a raw memory dump from a specific location, but I get "End of expression expected" error. If I attach [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg), then I can run same 'dd' command. How can I fix this problem?

```
!clrstack -l
OS Thread Id: 0xd5c (3420)
Child SP IP       Call Site
0050eeac 002700eb ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(System.String[])
    LOCALS:
        0x0050eeb0 = 0x0240c178
        0x0050eebc = 0x00000000

0050f0fc 6b4c21bb [GCFrame: 0050f0fc]

dd 0x0240c178
End of expression expected
dd 0x0050eeb0
End of expression expected
```

Comment: That command should work. I tested it in mine without any issues, using both managed and unmanaged code. How are you loading the sos dll in visual studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Immediate window you have to use `>dd 0x001AF2E0` to make it work.  You have to type the `>` before `dd`.

```
dd 0x001AF2E0
End of expression expected

>dd 0x001AF2E0
0x001AF2E0  6d7c4938 ffffffff 001af34c 00000001  
0x001AF2F0  002dd780 00000000 002dd780 ffffffff  
0x001AF300  00000001 77a220f9 00000000 00713000  
0x001AF310  002711a8 00000001 00000000 00000000
```

In the Command window you can just type `dd 0x001AF2E0`.

Answer (score 1):

Type .cordll and see if the sos dll is loaded.

eg:

0:000> .cordll

CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscordacwks.dll